# REST GeoServer services for anonymous users gives me 404 status

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to access to a REST service by an anonymous user on GeoServer 2.9.4. I modified my **resp.properties** file to allow anonymous role free access to GET:

> /**;GET=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
>
> /**;POST,DELETE,PUT=ADMIN;

Once I did this, the service gives me 404 status instead 401, and browser mode gives me an empty result, for example for service **/geoserver/rest/layers/layer_name**, I get:

No such layer: layer_name

But for service: **/geoserver/rest/styles** everything works great.

What am I missing?

Comment: why would you do that? an anonymous user could now delete all your data.

Comment: Hi, maybe I was not clear, but what I want is to open GET, to consult, no more.

Comment: REST is an administrative interface in GeoServer users should always authenticate to it - in fact that may be enforced by the code

Comment: I think that's not true, that would take away usability. As you can find on documentation there is possible configuration to achieve this: [Read only access to anonymous](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/rest#providing-anonymous-read-only-access) , even if I try to acces to service **/geoserver/rest/styles** it works, but is not the same for layer information in service like **/geoserver/rest/layers**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achived a right configuration to use */rest/layers/layer_name* as anonymous user. The problem was that there is another security seccion to configure called as "Data security" where I have to change the configuration from mode **HIDE** to mode **CHALLENGE** to allow access to layer's data.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't see a reason to allow anonymous users access to the admin interface but if you must then please [**read** the documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/rest#providing-anonymous-read-only-access).

You need to use `/**;GET=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've already tried this configuration and it works but for some rest seccions like "rest/styles" but it doesn't work for "rest/layers"

Comment: please edit your question to give us all the information